# is it possible to trigger your app by voice command from anywhere?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a way to add some background service that allows a user to trigger my app on specific keyword? Just like 'ok google' but 'ok app'?

If not, can I add some service to my app that will always listen and trigger actions based on voice commands?

I'm working on alarm clock with voice control.

Comment: I see on your profile that you never accept answers, might be nice to start doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! The [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/) offers hotword functionality that allows you to register custom triggers!

Check out [Actions for Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/).

Comment: That's not exactly what i was looking for, but thanks for the answer

Comment: No problem. How so if I may ask? You can integrate this SDK in your app so that you can control it using your voice, exactly like the 'ok Google' method (in fact it is using this same technology). The only difference is that you will probably have to start each conversation with 'ok Google' instead of 'ok app'.

Comment: thats the thing. I need it without 'ok Google'. I need to run commands directly in app, without google

Comment: Hmmm, maybe check out [pocketsphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx) and use it to create a background service that is always listening?